# How to remove all line spacing in ConTeXt

Tags: spacing, context, line-spacing

I am trying to remove all spacing between lines (be it from paragraphs, lineheight or line spacing) with [setupinterlinespace](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupinterlinespace), but I am not quite successful:

[image: no modifications]
[image: uncommented]

The left illustrates the default, the right after applying `setupinterlinespace`.
I have no idea why the command adds spacing for smaller font sizes and would be thankful for a remedy (does not matter whether it uses `setupinterlinespace`, but it would be nice if I would not have to add it to every single paragraph).

This is the corresponding MKIV code:

```tex
\setupinterlinespace[line=0cm,top=0,minheight=0,mindepth=0,stretch=0,bottom=0]
\starttext
\switchtobodyfont[30pt]
Testtext

Testtext

\switchtobodyfont[5pt]
Testtext

Testtext
\stoptext
```

While I do set all `setupinterlinespace` parameters in this example, only `line` seemed to make any difference.

Edit: Using `\showlayout` I was able to verify the `lineheight` being at fault, which is interestingly locked at `14.4816pt` for me. Now how can I change that?

Answer (score 2):

After debugging for a while, I found out that `lineheight` is at fault and that `setupinterlinespace` does set that directly. Unfortunately, while `showlayout` shows the `lineheight` value, that term is barely ever used in the documentation.

The particular issue here was that a `lineheight` of `0` is invalid, so it defaulted to 14. This fixed it:

```
\setupinterlinespace[1pt]
```